# How do browsers determine the port to which they should make a request?

Tags: http, networking, request, port, portforwarding

When browsers create requests to web servers, they add a Layer 4 header that includes source and destination ports. The source port is a freely chosen random port on the client machine, while the destination port is either 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS. But what if the web server listens on a port other than 80 or 443? How does the request reach its destination?

I am aware of port forwarding, and we can also directly specify the port number in the URL in the format PROTOCOL://DOMAIN_NAME:PORT_NUMBER. Are there any other methods?

Comment: You answered your own question. At the browser level, the requested URL must explicitly specify the port if it is different than the protocol's default port. At the networking level, you have to use a forwarding proxy or port forwarding. I'm not aware of any other options.

Comment: Remy, thank you for your answer. However, I need to know which port I should specify in the URL. I can obtain the IP address from DNS servers, but how can I determine port number.

Comment: There is no way for a browser to *discover* a non-default port.  The port has to be stated up front in the URL itself, as you noted. For example, if the web server is listening for HTTP on port 8080, then the URL must be like `http://hostname:8080/path`. Then the browser will connect to port 8080 on the IP of `hostname`, and then send an HTTP request for `/path`

Comment: Got it. Just I've never seen port numbers in real site URLs. Most likely, they use either port forwarding or forwarding proxies. Thanks

Comment: Most public sites don't use arbitrary ports, they use well-established standard ports.  Internal sites tend to use non-standard ports.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will generally have support for a white-list of URL types.

There's often some disagreement about whether or not to describe them as schemes (the URL's prefix) or protocols (whatever is going over the wire).

But when the browser accepts a URL, if the port number is not specified in the URL, the default port will be used. Typically a browser have an internal  list (in other words, most will not obey `/etc/services`).

Browsers often have support for various forms of proxy, like "CONNECT" and various versions of "SOCKS", but typically browsers do not allow configurable re-direction of a default port, because these are widely-distributed end user applications.

Those proxy configs will send all the requests to the port of the proxy server. If you want to be really fancy, PAC files allow dynamic mapping of proxy usage.

From a coding perspective, if you are using URL references internally, you should think about using explicit port numbers at all time.